# Returning array of strings in C++, length and corruption

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a .NET guy, diving into the realm of C++/micro-controller stuff.

The following is a mockup of what I'm trying to do. I have a method which a value is passed in, and based on that value I want to return a different hard-coded array of strings.

When I step through this, my function in `main()` seems to work, and it looks like I'm returning the proper type in the function. I can set a breakpoint and see `files[0]` is the expected string, `files[1]` is the expected string, etc. I can step through the loop and set a watch for `files[i]` and I see the appropriate string. All is good there.

So two questions: How do I get how many elements are in the array? From reading a million posts, it seems like I'm not able to do this, right? Do I just need some end string (empty string, for example) that I need to check through as I loop through?

Second, you'll notice I have the `printf()` commented out. When I had that enabled, after stepping through the `printf()`, it would change the contents of the string, and I don't understand why it's doing that. See images for the before/after of the step-through and the result of the watches. I thought it might be because the strings aren't implicitly terminated with a `\0`, but that had no effect.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

const char** GetSoundCategory(int category)
{
    const char* FILES1[3] = {
        "/myfile1.mp3",
        "/this_is_my_file.mp3",
        "/myfile9.mp3"
    };

    const char* FILES2[2] = {
        "/I love S.E.mp3",
         "/please_help_me.mp3"
    };   

    const char** ptr = nullptr;

    switch (category)
    {
        case 1:
            ptr = FILES1;
            break;
        case 2:
            ptr = FILES2;
            break;
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    const char** files = GetSoundCategory(2);
    constexpr int number_of_files = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_files; i++)
    {
        //  printf("%s\n", files[i]);
    }
}
```

Before `printf`:

[image: Before printf]

After `printf`:

[image: After printf]

Comment: You return a pointer to a local variable. Declare the variables static.

Comment: Beautiful, that solves the printf dilemma. Can you provide more info on why this works? Is it just releasing memory of the local variables after the first printf? Can you answer the other question about the number of elements in the array?

Comment: Use and return `std::array` if the size is fixed, or `std::vector` if the size is variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code exhibits **undefined behavior**, in two different ways.

1. `GetSoundCategory()` is returning a pointer to a local variable that gets freed when `GetSoundCategory()` exits, thus the returned pointer is left *dangling*, pointing at invalid memory before the caller ever has a chance to use it.

   Since your arrays do not change, you can move them into global memory or static memory so that they stay alive after `GetSoundCategory()` exits, eg:

   ```
   static const char* FILES1[3] = {
       "/myfile1.mp3",
       "/this_is_my_file.mp3",
       "/myfile9.mp3"
   };

   static const char* FILES2[2] = {
       "/I love S.E.mp3",
       "/please_help_me.mp3"
   };   

   const char** GetSoundCategory(int category)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   const char** GetSoundCategory(int category)
   {
       static const char* FILES1[3] = {
           "/myfile1.mp3",
           "/this_is_my_file.mp3",
           "/myfile9.mp3"
       };

       static const char* FILES2[2] = {
           "/I love S.E.mp3",
            "/please_help_me.mp3"
       };   

       ...
   }
   ```
2. The way you have `GetSoundCategory()` coded, `main()` has no way of knowing how many strings are actually in the returned array.  So, when `category == 2`, it's loop ends up going out of bounds since there are only 2 strings in the array but the loop iterates 3 times.

   To solve this, you have a few options.  You can either:

   - null-terminate the arrays, eg:

     ```
     const char** GetSoundCategory(int category)
     {
         static const char* FILES1[4] = {
             "/myfile1.mp3",
             "/this_is_my_file.mp3",
             "/myfile9.mp3",
             nullptr
         };

         static const char* FILES2[3] = {
             "/I love S.E.mp3",
             "/please_help_me.mp3",
             nullptr
         };   

         ...
     }

     ...

     const char** files = GetSoundCategory(2);

     for (int i = 0; files[i] != nullptr; i++)
     {
         printf("%s\n", files[i]);
     }
     ```
   - return the array length as well as the array pointer.  You can do that with an output parameter, eg:

     ```
     const char** GetSoundCategory(int category, int *length)
     {
         ...

         *length = ...;
         return ...;
     }

     ...

     int number_of_files;
     const char** files = GetSoundCategory(2, &number_of_files);
     ```

     Or, return a simple `struct` that holds both the array pointer and the array length, eg:

     ```
     struct filesArray {
         const char** files;
         int number_of_files;
     };

     filesArray GetSoundCategory(int category)
     {
         ...

         filesArray fa;
         fa.files = ...;
         fa.number_of_files = ...;

         return fa;
     }

     ...

     filesArray fa = GetSoundCategory(2);

     for (int i = 0; i < fa.number_of_files; i++)
     {
         printf("%s\n", fa.files[i]);
     }
     ```

---

That being said, you really should ditch the old C-based idioms in your code and embrace more modern C++ idioms, like `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::string(_view)`, etc, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

std::vector<std::string_view> GetSoundCategory(int category)
{
    static std::array<const char*, 3> FILES1 = {
        "/myfile1.mp3",
        "/this_is_my_file.mp3",
        "/myfile9.mp3"
    };

    static std::array<const char*, 2> FILES2 = {
        "/I love S.E.mp3",
        "/please_help_me.mp3"
    };   

    switch (category)
    {
        case 1:
            return {FILES1.begin(), FILES1.end()};
        case 2:
            return {FILES2.begin(), FILES2.end()};
    }

    return {};
}

int main()
{
    auto files = GetSoundCategory(2);

    for (auto file : files)
    {
        std::cout << file << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)(C++20) is another option over `std::vector`.

Comment: std::vector was incredibly easy to use and very intuitive, thanks to both of you!